# Using GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to update vertice data

Tags: c++, opengl

This is a beginner level OpenGL C++ Question

I try to update a triangle offset using GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. Here is a minimal exampe that illustrates my problem. `#define crashversion` is used to enable the version that i think should work but results in a crash. it that `#define` is removed the remainder of the source works. I am still a beginner so i am using some functionality that is not visible here. `AyOpenGL::GlShader;` `AyOpenGL::GlProgram;` are thin helper classes that manage memory and loading of shaders and programs. They have been proven to work with all my other functionality. `sb6::application` is a helper class from the OpenGL super bible 6th edition. I am very sure that those are reasonably bug free and that my understanding of opengl buffers are at the core of the problem. I can edit and support snippets if that would help the anser.

```
class stackexample : public sb6::application
{
private:
    GLuint vertex_array_Object;
    GLuint buffer;
    std::unique_ptr<AyOpenGL::GlProgram> program;
public:
    void render(double currentTime);
    void startup();
    void shutdown();
};

#define crashversion

void stackexample::startup()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<GlShader>> shaders;
    shaders.push_back(make_shared<GlShader>("Shaders//VS_Triangle_IN_offset.c", GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
    shaders.push_back(make_shared<GlShader>("Shaders//FS_CyanColor.c", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
    program = std::make_unique<GlProgram>("program", shaders);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_Object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_Object);
#ifdef crashversion
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1000, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
#endif
}

void stackexample::render(double currentTime)
{
    GLfloat black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat offset[] = { (float)std::sin(currentTime), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);
    glUseProgram(*program);
#ifdef crashversion
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(offset), offset);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
#else
    glVertexAttrib4fv(0, offset);
#endif
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void stackexample::shutdown()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_Object);
}
```

VS_Triangle_IN_offset.c:

```
#version 430 core                                                 

layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset;

void main(void)                                                   
{                                                                 
    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),
                                   vec4( 0.25,  0.25, 0.5, 1.0));
    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;
}
```

FS_CyanColor.c:

```
#version 430 core    

out vec4 color;

void main(void)      
{
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

My understanding is that i push the offset into the shader via the buffer in both versions. Somehow though the second version does not function and i have no clue why. I tried different constellations of the code and tried to research this but i was unable to educate myself here.

How can the `crashversion` be written so that it does the exact same thing as the normal version?

EDIT:
I was very loose in using the word crash. It crashes somewhat undefined but mostly like this: Unhandled exception at 0x04A025AD (nvoglv32.dll) in OpenGLDemo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

So it looks like a nullpointer problem

Comment: How does it crash? Does it segfault? Run your code in a debugger and it should pause on where it crashes; from there, you can get a backtrace and see where it's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set up a vertex attrib pointer for attribute 0, so you never use the VBO you created. However, you enable the array for attribute zero, which will result in the GL accessing some totally invalid memory location - which is likely to crash.

Maybe the [OpenGL wiki entry on Vertex Specification](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) might help you in understanding the concepts.

Comment: Ah, that sounds consistent with the error. I will read through the manual and check the box when i fixed my demo.

Answer (score 0):

As @derhass pointed out reading additional documentation cleared some things up.

Here are the changes i made to the code in order to make it run.

```
void stackexample::startup()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<GlShader>> shaders;
    shaders.push_back(make_shared<GlShader>("Shaders//VS_Triangle_IN_offset.c", GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
    shaders.push_back(make_shared<GlShader>("Shaders//FS_CyanColor.c", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
    program = std::make_unique<GlProgram>("program", shaders);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_Object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_Object);
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1000, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void stackexample::render(double currentTime)
{
    GLfloat black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat vertex_offset[] = { (float)std::sin(currentTime), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);
    glUseProgram(*program);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertex_offset), vertex_offset);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_offset), sizeof(vertex_offset), vertex_offset);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * sizeof(vertex_offset), sizeof(vertex_offset), vertex_offset);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

I can see the additional improvement potential but i went for the minimal change in the example.